# fill 2 form one field in common with C#

Tags: c#, forms, browser

I need to fill two forms on the same website, my issue is the field because they have the same name, e.g. the password field in both forms is passed, so how can I fill both?

```html
<form  action="post.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
  <input type="text" name="image" />
  <input type="password" name="pass" size="10" tabindex="7" accesskey="Q" value="">
</form>
```

```html
<form action="post2.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
  <input type="text" name="image" />
  <input type="password" name="pass" size="10" tabindex="4" accesskey="P" value="">
</form>
```

the code to fill fields I'm using is this:
`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", stringpassword);`

thanks

Comment: some HTML would help (including the surrounding html). if they have the same ID, then its invalid XHTML. is jQuery an option? if not, you'll have to write a custom regex-based document.getElementsByClassName function.

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element.
The id must be unique within the HTML document.
The id attribute can be used by a JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) or by CSS to make changes or style the element with the specified id.

And if your specified website is not following the standard Html practices then you should write your own custom 
code to access those controls and fill them straight away. You can use Regex Or Xpath for accomplishing this purpose.

Comment: <form  action="post.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
  <input type="text" name="image" />
<input type="password" name="pass" size="10" tabindex="7" accesskey="Q" value="">
</form>


<form action="post2.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
  <input type="text" name="image" />
<input type="password" name="pass" size="10" tabindex="4" accesskey="P" value="">
</form>

Comment: I can't post html code well formatted
sorry :(
but look the password field
there are 2 forms they have the same name fields
let say I need to fill this fields
<input type="password" name="pass" size="10" tabindex="7" accesskey="Q" value="">
and
<input type="password" name="pass" size="10" tabindex="4" accesskey="P" value="">